# Securing Folder on EC2 Amazon Marketplace AMI

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm planning to start a small business and submit an Linux AMI to Amazon's AWS Marketplace.  As I'm reading the seller's guide, I see this:

> AMIs MUST allow OS-level administration capabilities to allow for compliance requirements, vulnerability updates and log file access. For Linux-based AMIs this is through SSH." ([6.2.2](http://awsmp-loadforms.s3.amazonaws.com/AWS_Marketplace_-_Seller_Guide.pdf))

How can I protect my source code if anyone who uses my product can SSH to the machine and poke around?  Can I lock down certain folders yet still allow "os-level administration"?

---

Here is a bit of context if needed:

- I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type (ami-cd0f5cb6) as my base AMI
- I'm provisioning a slightly modified MySQL database that I want my customers to be able to access.  This is their primary way of interacting with my service.
- I'm building a django web service that will come packaged on the AMI. This is what I'd like to lock down and prevent access to.

Comment: Not exactly an answer but to alleviate your problem, maybe (just guessing) you could provide some sort of well obfuscated bootstrap program that checks if there is an active AWS Marketplace subscription in place and allows to run your application (obfuscated too) only if it verifies so.

Comment: Seems like AWS are trying to get this question pushed down in SE indexes. Your code and IP are not safe if you sell through AWS marketplace. There’s no option to prevent buyer access to the instance or volumes. Surprising they didn’t come up with something yet.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not you provide SSH access, it'll always be possible for your users to mount the root EBS-volume of your AMI on another EC2-instance to investigate its contents, so disabling SSH or making certain files unreadable for an SSH-user doesn't help you in this regard.

Instead of trying to to keep users away from your source code I suggest you simply state clearly what the users are allowed to do with it and what not in the terms of service.

Even large companies provide OS-images which contain the source code of their applications (whenever they use a scripting language) in clear form or just slightly obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I didn't realize they could attach the volume to any other instance.  That makes sense though.