# How to protect source code in aws from client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am developing some projects for one client. I put all the code in aws ec2 instance. I don't want to give the code access to client.

Client will have aws account id password.

Can I protect source code access in aws such that the client can do and see other things but not the code.

Comment: So, you own the code and they don't? Can you program in a language that does not require you to deliver source code (for example C, C++, Java, C#)?

Comment: @jarmod My code is in php

Answer (score 1):

You could provide them access to the `aws console` but not hand them programmatic access/ssh-access to the instances.

If they want ssh access and your programms require source code I don't see any possibility to hide the code.

You could however, in your contract state that your code is your property and not allowed to be reused etc..

Reference
[Securing Folder on EC2 Amazon Marketplace AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46079902/9177173)

Edit:
I created a user with console access but without any rights. As you can see he does not see my instances running. Hence he can not copy them whatsoever. You could however grant access to certain products such as cloud watch so he can monitor the logs.
[image: User with console access but no rights]

Comment: Even if i don't give ssh access, client can copy the instance, generate new key pair and get access to data. How to prevent this ?

Comment: But permission is controlled by the person who has aws account credential and client will have that.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-a-limited-iam-administrator-by-using-managed-policies/  - you can restrict permissions even for users with credentials

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will check this. But i think user which has aws account credential is kind of super admin which can override all type of settings.

Comment: Of course you have to be the owner of the root aws account